# How can I associate a project to an agent pool on TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity, agent, buildconfiguration, agents

For my automated tests I have a project added to TeamCity server and 2 Agent Pool, one is a Windows Server and the other one is a MAC. The default agent pool is WIN but I wanted to run my tests on the MAC server. To change the agent pool to MAC, I tried to add Agent Requirement by setting     `teamcity.agent.name` to the `MAC server` from the list but it is not added to list of compatible agents associated with the project, but added to compatible agents with this warning on top of it: `Following agents belong to the agent pools which are not associated with "Tests" project` where Tests is the name of my project.

How can I associate it MAC agent to my project?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You'll have to add the MAC agent to the agent pool for this project - that's configured in the Agent section available at `/agents.html?tab=agentPools` for your TeamCity build server.

Alternatively you can create a new agent pool with the MAC agent, and add the project to that pool.

Comment: Thanks @BronkenGlass I added a new pool and associate my project to it.